# SPDispose Ignore attribute not ignoring

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In my SharePoint code, I have the following line:

`SPWeb web = site.RootWeb; //site is an SPSite object`

When I rebuild my project and run the SPDispose tool on the assembly, I get the following error:

---

> Module: Blah.SharePoint.Features.Core.dll Method:
>   Blah.SharePoint.Features.Core.Helpers.FeatureDeploymentHelper.RemoveWebPartFiles(Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureReceiverProperties,System.String)
>   Statement: web := site.{Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite}get_RootWeb()
>   Source:
>   C:\xxx\xxx\Main\Source\SharePoint\Features\Core\Helpers\FeatureDeploymentHelper.cs
>   Line: 26
>
> Notes:     Disposable type not disposed: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb
>   ***This may be a false positive depending on how the type was created or if it is disposed outside the current scope More Information:
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/rogerla/archive/2008/02/12/sharepoint-2007-and-wss-3-0-dispose-patterns-by-example.aspx#SPDisposeCheckID_140

---

What I want to do is to have the SPDispose tool ignore this error, so I have pulled the SPDisposeCheckIgnore class and supporting enum into my project, and I've decorated my method appropriately:

```
[SPDisposeCheckIgnore(SPDisposeCheckID.SPDisposeCheckID_140, "RootWeb does not need disposed.")]

public static void RemoveWebPartFiles(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties, string assemblyName)
{ 
...
}
```

After doing all of this, I still receive the error.  Anyone know how I might go about getting rid of that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things need to be done here.

1) The SPDisposeCheckIgnore class must be defined in the SPDisposeCheck namespace.  You CANNOT have your own namespace.  See the related comment on this page: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SPDisposeCheck/

2) Anything you are trying to ignore within RunWithElevatedPrivleges must be pulled into an external method or it will not be recognized.  This was not being done in the example above, but was being done in other places.

These two rules must be followed for ignore to work.  Hope this helps someone else down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Double check how you're retrieving and assigning the `RootWeb` object.  If it's done in an external method, the `DisposeChecker` might not pick up that it's a `RootWeb` reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with what you've written. I pulled out getting the root web into a static method so I only had to ignore this error in one place, and [it works in anonymous delegates](http://www.novolocus.com/2011/06/01/practical-spdisposecheck-namespaces-delegates-and-rootwebs/). The following worked for me:

```
public class DisposeUtils
{

    [SPDisposeCheckIgnore(SPDisposeCheckID.SPDisposeCheckID_140, "RootWeb does not need disposed. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rogerla/archive/2009/11/30/sharepoint-2007-2010-do-not-dispose-guidance-spdisposecheck.aspx")]
    public static SPWeb GetRootWeb(SPSite site)
    {
        return site.RootWeb;
    }
}
```

Sorry, I'm not sure if that helps exactly - I'm saying your code should work. Have you checked SPDisposeCheck to see how it handles 'Documented' and 'Undocumented' errors? (I've never been entirely clear what those settings do)

Comment: I've tried this as well...still no dice.  I'm going to pull down some example code this weekend and see if I can't get that work.  Thanks for looking into this.